# Apache "Require group foo" not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to configure apache such that every access requires SSO authentication via mod_auth_mellon. I already have this working perfectly:

```
<Location />
    AuthType "Mellon"
    Require valid-user
    ...
</Location>
```

Now I want to further restrict certain deeper directories based on the authenticated user's group, where this group information comes from a local file in the filesystem (e.g. /etc/group or something else of my choosing):

```
<Location /some_dir>
    Require group foo
</Location>
```

I can't seem to find any combination of AuthType, AuthGroupFile, AuthMerging, etc in that second  block that does group checking. Instead, accesses always succeed and my debug log contains the following:

```
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814390 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814438 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814444 2021] [core:trace3] request.c(312): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /some_dir/
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814513 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814520 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814527 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814530 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814630 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814639 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814645 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
[Wed Jun 02 19:50:21.814649 2021] [authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.74.101.90:54850] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

I don't understand what's happening here. Specifically, what is this?

> request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook:
> /some_dir/

Also, I have no <RequireAny> directives anywhere in my configuration so I'm not sure why that ends up in the log.

Is it possible to configure apache to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this working. The trick was to put `AuthMerging And` in the `<Location />` block rather than in the `<Location /some_dir>` block. This was not clear to me from the documentation which says:

> When a configuration section contains `AuthMerging And` or `AuthMerging Or`,
> its authorization logic is combined with that of the nearest
> predecessor (according to the overall order of configuration sections)
> which also contains authorization logic as if the two sections were
> jointly contained within a `<RequireAll>` or `<RequireAny>` directive,
> respectively.

The order of `<Location />` and `<Location /some_dir>` in my configuration does not seem to matter but the location of `AuthMerging And` ***does*** matter.